# Sum a variable for consecutive actions of another variable using rle

Tags: r, dplyr, rle

I have only used the rle function to run queries that give me the n() of a condition but now I need to find consecutive streaks of one variable and group each streak together so I can sum the total of another column. dput example given to show what I mean below.

What I want to find is the amount of consecutive points each player scores just for his team. The data below is a chronological order of plays and "possession" indicates which of the two teams scored the shot. "player_fg" shows which player that was. "pts" is the column I want to add for each player. For Example, Scottie Pippen scored the final four shots for the Chicago Bulls and thus the answer should be 8 total points for him.

I can write a rle code that adds one for each consecutive player on the same team that makes a shot but it doesn't add all of those made shots together.

```
df %>% 
group_by(gameid, possession) %>% 
mutate(marker = ifelse(player_fg != lag(player_fg), 1, 
sequence(rle(player_fg)$lengths))) %>% 
view
```

That's where I get stuck.

dput for reproducibility:

```
structure(list(season = c("96/97", "96/97", "96/97", "96/97", 
"96/97", "96/97", "96/97", "96/97", "96/97", "96/97"), gameid = 
c("ChicagoBoston19961101", 
"ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101", 
"ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101", 
"ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101", "ChicagoBoston19961101"
), possession = c("Chicago", "Chicago", "Boston", "Boston", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Boston", "Boston", "Chicago"), pts = c(2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2), player_fg = c("D. Rodman", "D. Rodman", 
"D. Wesley", "E. Williams", "S. Pippen", "S. Pippen", "S. Pippen", 
"P. Ellison", "P. Ellison", "S. Pippen")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ronakshah I know you made a YT video on rle. Would you be able to adapt it to answer this in a grouped dplyr form?

Comment: Would `df %>% group_by(player_fg) %>% summarize(marker = sum(pts))` achieve your desired result? If that's not it, it might be useful if you manually created a small example of what you want your final output to look like.